# How to show the specified table row data based on the filter option in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table, react-class-based-component

I am new to reactjs. I am showing the json data in the table. I also want to display only specific table row data for the specific filter option.
Here I want when noida is selected then the table should display only 2 nd 3rd row of the table.
when Moradabad is selected the it should display only first row of the table.

Here I am attaching the image which displays all the rows , please help me in this filtration logic show only on selected city.

[image]

The code is below

```
    import React from 'react';
    import './style.css';
    
    export default class JsonDataDisplay extends React.Component {
     
     constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          data: [
            {
              id: 1,
              name: 'Akshit',
              city: 'Moradabad',        
            },
    
            {
              id: 2,
              name: 'Nikita',
              city: 'Noida',
            },
    
            {
              id: 3,
              name: 'Deeksha',
              city: 'Noida',
             }
          ],
        };
      }
      render() {
        const displaydata = this.state.data.map((info) => (
          <tr>
            <td>{info.id}</td>
            <td>{info.name}</td>
            <td>{info.city}</td>
          </tr>
        ));
    
        return (
          <>
            <FilterComponent />
            <br />
            <section>
              <table>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>name</th>
                    <th>city</th>  
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>{displaydata}</tbody>
              </table>
            </section>
          </>
        );
      }
    }
    
    
    
    function FilterComponent(props) {
      const data = ['All', 'Noida', 'Moradabad'];
      return (
        <div>
          <div>city</div>
          <select>
            {data.map((field) => (
              <option>{field}</option>
            ))}
          </select>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few more things to do,

1. Define another state variable to keep the `selectedCity` state

```
    this.state = {
      data: [
         ...
         ...
      ],
      selectedCity: "All"
    };
```

2. Define a onChange handler function to set the selected city

```
  setSelectedCity = (selectedCity) => {
    this.setState({ selectedCity });
  };
```

3. Add a filter for `displaydata` as below

```
const displaydata = this.state.data
      .filter(
        ({ city }) =>
          this.state.selectedCity === "All" || this.state.selectedCity === city
      )
      .map((info) => (
        <tr>
          <td>{info.id}</td>
          <td>{info.name}</td>
          <td>{info.city}</td>
        </tr>
      ));
```

4. Pass `setSelectedCity` as a prop to `FilterComponent`

```
<FilterComponent setSelectedCity={this.setSelectedCity} />
```

5. Update the `FilterComponent` to set the `selectedCity` when selection changes.

```
function FilterComponent({ setSelectedCity }) {
  const data = ["All", "Noida", "Moradabad"];
  return (
    <div>
      <div>city</div>
      <select onChange={(e) => setSelectedCity(e.target.value)}>
        {data.map((field) => (
          <option value={field}>{field}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-christian-towqy?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: @Sathish, check this out !!